Kotlin generic interface used in Map of that same interface
I have the following implementations:
interface Validator<T: Request<R>, R> {

    fun validate(paymentCmd: T): Pair<ValidationResult, R>
}

The interface Request have nothing, it is just for the purpose of the implementations.
class ValidatorProvider() {

    private val validators: MutableMap<PaymentAction, Validator<Request<Any?>, Any?>> = mutableMapOf()

    fun register(action: PaymentAction, validator: Validator<Request<Any?>, Any?>){
        validators[action] = validator
    }

    fun get(action: PaymentAction): Validator<Request<Any?>, Any?> {
        return validators[action] ?: throw Exception("Use custom exception here.")
    }
}

And finally a service with the previous provider. The idea is that this Service, using the providers, can retreive the correct validator and handler implementations and process the input.
interface PaymentService {

    fun <T: Request<R>, R> process(paymentCmd: T, action: PaymentAction): R
}

@Component
class PaymentServiceImpl(private val validatorProvider: ValidatorProvider,
                         private val handlerProvider: HandlerProvider
): PaymentService {

    override fun <T: Request<R>, R> process(paymentCmd: T, action: PaymentAction): R {

        val result = validatorProvider.get(action).validate(paymentCmd)

        if(result.first.status == ValidationStatus.FAILED){
            return result.second
        }

        return handlerProvider.get(action).process(paymentCmd)
    }
}

The first problem is in line val result = validatorProvider.get(action).validate(paymentCmd)
Type mismatch.
Required: Request<Any?>
Found: T

I do not know how to declare private val validators: MutableMap<PaymentAction, Validator<Request<Any?>, Any?>> = mutableMapOf() in order to be able for the code to work.
I have been playing with covariance and contravariance to see if the problem is there, but no luck, can you help me please.

The moment you have such a map like validators, this becomes inherently unsafe. Do some unchecked casts if you are sure that the types are correct.

Can you guide me how pls? I'm kind of new to Kotlin

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
